# SDL Surface returning NULL?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm getting a segmentation Fault and I've tracked it to my surface, which is NULL (but the Check in place doesn't trigger).

I'm unsure if i'm creating the surface correctly. Is there something I need to add when creating the Surface, Something that I've missed?

```
bool init()
{
    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set texture filtering to linear
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" ) )
        {
            printf( "Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!" );
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create window
            gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "kPaint", 575, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
            GUI = SDL_CreateWindow( "GUI", 0, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 573, 542, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

            if( gWindow == NULL || GUI == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Create renderer for window
                gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

                if( gRenderer == NULL )
                {
                    printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                    return false;
                }
                surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
                GUIsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( GUI );

                if( surface == NULL )
                {
                    printf( "surface could not be created!" );
                    return false;
                }
                SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 255,255,255));

                //Initialize PNG loading
                int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) && imgFlags ) )
                {
                    printf( "SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError() );
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try not creating a renderer before SDL_GetWindowSurface(). I might be wrong, but iirc SDL does not allow you to get the window surface once you have created a renderer for that window

Comment: If it's not null immediately after you created it, but is null later, you must have done something to change it inbetween.

Comment: Furthermore, you could check the return value of SDL_FillRect(), to see if something went wrong there

Comment: Thank you So much, guys. I was soo stressed over this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you NeoAgglos.

I was Creating a renderer before the surfaces.

```
bool init()
{
    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set texture filtering to linear
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" ) )
        {
            printf( "Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!" );
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create window
            gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "kPaint", 575, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
            GUI = SDL_CreateWindow( "GUI", 0, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 573, 542, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

            if( gWindow == NULL || GUI == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
                GUIsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( GUI );

                if( surface == NULL )
                {
                    printf( "surface could not be created!" );
                    return false;
                }
                SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 255,255,255));

                //Create renderer for window
                gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );
                if( gRenderer == NULL )
                {
                    printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                    return false;
                }

                //Initialize PNG loading
                int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) && imgFlags ) )
                {
                    printf( "SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError() );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. You've fooled SDL's internal error check but it doesn't make it correct. SDL manual for `SDL_GetWindowSurface` explicitly states you can't mix it with rendering API.